# Custom post type: check permissions and validate nonce

Tags: custom-post-types, permissions, nonce

I have a custom post type with the following capabilities:

```
$capabilities = array(
    'read_post' => 'administrator',
    'read_private_posts' => 'administrator',
    'publish_posts' => 'administrator',
    'edit_post' => 'administrator',
    'edit_posts' => 'administrator',
    'edit_published_posts' => 'administrator',
    'edit_others_posts' => 'administrator',
    'edit_private_posts' => 'administrator',
    'delete_post' => 'administrator',
    'delete_posts' => 'administrator',
    'delete_published_posts' => 'administrator',
    'delete_others_posts' => 'administrator',
    'delete_private_posts' => 'administrator'
);
```

Do I still need to use something like `current_user_can()` when saving (via `save_post`), to validate whether that user has permissions to add or edit a post, or does setting the capabilities take care of that?

Since this is not a custom page in Wordpress, but rather a custom post type, do I need to verify the nonce or is this built-in when using a custom post type? I should note that I'm not using any Wordpress fields (such as title, body, etc) in that post type. There is one pair of fields that have been added using `add_meta_box()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `save_post` you are usually add/updating user-inputted data from a metabox into the database. When do this you should check that **your** metabox's nonce is valid.

You should also check permissions as `save_post` is triggered inside `wp_insert_post()`, and not just when the you create/edit a post admin side.